# Cannot retrieve query term from form in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a News App using React JS which fetches data from News API(https://newsapi.org). I have used the NavBar from bootstrap(with a form in it). My goal is to retrieve the term entered in the form, pass it to the URL which is used to request to News API, and display the news relevant to the searched term. But nothing happens when I press enter after typing the query term in the form.

Here is the code for **Home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../styles/Home.css";
import News from "./News";
import { Link as ScrollLink } from "react-scroll";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default class Home extends Component {
  buttonStyle = {
    display: "block",
    margin: "auto",
    textColor: "black",
  };

  divStyle = {
    marginTop: 30,
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pageSize: 10,
      category: this.props.category,
      query: ""
    };
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      query: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    // alert(`${this.state.query} was your query`);
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      // Navbar
      <>
        <div>
          <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <div className="container-fluid">
              <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">
                RapidNews
              </Link>
              <button
                className="navbar-toggler"
                type="button"
                data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav"
                aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation"
              >
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul className="navbar-nav">
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link className="nav-link " aria-current="page" to="/">
                      Home
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/general">
                      General
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/business">
                      Business
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/entertainment">
                      Entertainment
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/health">
                      Health
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/science">
                      Science
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/sports">
                      Sports
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/technology">
                      Technology
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>

              <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="d-flex">
                <input
                autoFocus
                  className="form-control me-2"
                  type="search"
                  placeholder="Search"
                  aria-label="Search"
                  value={this.state.query}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-outline-success">
                  Search
                </button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>

        {/* Main Home Page */}

        <div className=" d-flex flex-column container ">
          <div className="container d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
            <h1 className="text-center y py-5 my-4">RapidNews</h1>
            <h3 className="my-4" style={this.buttonStyle}>
              Your Ultimate News Solution
            </h3>
          </div>
          <ScrollLink to="news_section" smooth={true} duration={90}>
            <button
              type="button"
              className="btn btn-dark btn-grad mx-7 my-4 px-3"
              style={this.buttonStyle}
            >
              Go to News
            </button>
          </ScrollLink>

          <div id="news_section">
            <News
              key="general"
              pageSize={this.state.pageSize}
              country="in"
              category={this.state.category}
              query={this.state.query}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the code of **News.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import NewsItem from "./NewsItem";
import Spinner from "./Spinner";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Link } from "react-scroll/modules";
// import { query } from "./NavBar";

export default class News extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    country: "in",
    pageSize: 6,
    category: "general",
    query: ""
  };

  static propTypes = {
    country: PropTypes.string,
    pageSize: PropTypes.number,
    category: PropTypes.string,
  };


  articles = [];
  
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      articles: this.articles,
      loading: false,
      page: 1,
      disableNextButton: false,
      // queryTerm: query,
    };
  }
  

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    let url = ""
    if (this.props.query) {
      url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?q=${this.props.query}&country=${this.props.country}&pageSize=${this.props.pageSize}&apiKey=myapikey`;
      
    } else {
      url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&category=${this.props.category}&pageSize=${this.props.pageSize}&apiKey=myapikey`;
    }
    let data = await fetch(url);
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    let parsedData = await data.json();
    console.log(parsedData);
    console.log(this.props.query);
    this.setState({
      articles: parsedData.articles,
      totalResults: parsedData.totalResults,
      loading: false,
    });
    console.log(this.totalResults);
  }

  handlePrevClick = async () => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
   let url = ""
    if (this.props.query) {
      url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?q=${this.props.query}&country=${this.props.country}&pageSize=${this.props.pageSize}&apiKey=myapikey`;
      
    } else {
      url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&category=${this.props.category}&pageSize=${this.props.pageSize}&apiKey=myapikey`;
    }
    let data = await fetch(url);
    let parsedData = await data.json();
    this.setState({
      articles: parsedData.articles,
      page: this.state.page - 1,
      disableNextButton: false,
      loading: false,
    });
  };

  handleNextClick = async () => {
    if (
      Math.ceil(this.state.totalResults / this.props.pageSize) <
      this.state.page + 1
    ) {
      this.setState({ loading: true });
      let url = ""
      if (this.props.query) {
        url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?q=${this.props.query}&country=${this.props.country}&pageSize=${this.props.pageSize}&apiKey=myapikey`;
        
      } else {
        url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&category=${this.props.category}&pageSize=${this.props.pageSize}&apiKey=myapikey`;
      }
      let data = await fetch(url);
      let parsedData = await data.json();

      this.setState({
        articles: parsedData.articles,
        page: this.state.page + 1,
        disableNextButton: false,
        loading: false,
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ loading: true });
      let url = ""
      if (this.props.query) {
        url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?q=${this.props.query}&country=${this.props.country}&pageSize=${this.props.pageSize}&apiKey=myapikey`;
        
      } else {
        url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&category=${this.props.category}&pageSize=${this.props.pageSize}&apiKey=myapikey`;
      }
      let data = await fetch(url);
      let parsedData = await data.json();

      this.setState({
        articles: parsedData.articles,
        page: this.state.page + 1,
        disableNextButton: true,
        loading: false,
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container my-3" id="news_starting">
        {this.state.loading ? (
          <Spinner />
        ) : (
          <div>
            {/* <h2 className="text-center my-3">RapidNews</h2> */}
            <div className="container d-flex justify-content-between">
              <button
                disabled={this.state.page <= 1}
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-dark"
                onClick={this.handlePrevClick}
              >
                &larr; Previous
              </button>

              <Link to="news_ending" smooth={true} duration={90}>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-dark">
                  Jump to Bottom &darr;
                </button>
              </Link>

              <button
                disabled={this.state.disableNextButton}
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-dark"
                onClick={this.handleNextClick}
              >
                Next &rarr;
              </button>
            </div>

            <div className="row my-3">
              {this.state.articles.map((article) => {
                return (
                  <div className="col-md-3" key={article.url}>
                    <NewsItem
                      title={article.title}
                      description={article.description}
                      urlToImage={article.urlToImage}
                      newsUrl={article.url}
                      author={article.author}
                      source={article.source.name}
                      publishedAt={article.publishedAt}
                    />
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>

            <div
              className="container d-flex justify-content-between"
              id="news_ending"
            >
              <button
                disabled={this.state.page <= 1}
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-dark"
                onClick={this.handlePrevClick}
              >
                &larr; Previous
              </button>

              <Link to="news_starting" smooth={true} duration={90}>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-dark">
                  Jump to Top &uarr;
                </button>
              </Link>

              <button
                disabled={this.state.disableNextButton}
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-dark"
                onClick={this.handleNextClick}
              >
                Next &rarr;
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What should I do to make my idea work?

Comment: Nothing happens when you press enter because nothing is done in the `handleSubmit` callback

Comment: @ColdAtNight Okay, so what should I do in order to pass the term I enter in as a prop in **News.js** (rendered in **Home.js**)?